# Knockout Js Dropdown not loading with values from WebAPi Service

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, html.dropdownlistfor

Knockout Js Dropdown not loading with values from WebAPi Service

Code is as below, Please help me.

This is the knock out js call for drop down

```
<select data-bind="options: menus, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'pk_smartMenuID',  optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Web APi Call

```
    // GET api/SmartMenu
    public IEnumerable<SmartMenu> GetSmartMenus()
    {
        var smartmenus = _db.SmartMenus.Include(s => s.ParentSmartMenu);
        return smartmenus.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

This is the View Model ( script) to contact web api server call

```
@section Scripts { 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout") 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function MenuViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        var baseUri = '@ViewBag.ApiUrl';
        self.menus = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.selectedMenu = ko.observable();

        self.addMenu = function(formElement) {
          // If valid, post the serialized form data to the web api 
          $(formElement).validate();
          if ($(formElement).valid()) {
            $.post(baseUri, $(formElement).serialize(), null, "json")
            .done(function(o) { self.menus.push(o); });
          }
        };

        $.getJSON(baseUri, self.menus);
      }

      $(document).ready(function() {
        ko.applyBindings(new MenuViewModel());
      });
</script> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the json data is in Linkedlist need to iterate,
I  got the answer in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html